# VBA - Custom Plugin works perfectly on laptop however does not work on other computers

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ms-word

I am currently having issues with a custom plugin that I was assigned from my boss which was not fully tested and developed at the time it was assigned. It is a letter template generator that takes values from Access (Letter Type, account Type, agent list,etc) which generates a sheet in excel which the user can enter values into based on the bookmarks within the word document.

The communication between Access and Excel appears to be fine, the issue is when the data is going from excel to word there is a part of my code removes the word.formfields replaces them with bookmarks and changes the value afterwards based on the user entry within the excel sheet, this section of the code works fine on my work laptop and my work desktop but not on the desktop of the advisors who are using the tool.

The strange thing about it is that the deleting of the word.formfield is fine it's just the changing of the bookmark that is not working. The following is the code that appears to be malfunctioning on only some computers:

The if statement that is below to update the bookmark is to check for specific bookmarks to assign them, unfortunately I cannot link that code here.

I have already Checked the other computer's security settings and version numbers and they are the same as mine so I really have no idea what could be causing this...

Update Bookmark:

```
        ElseIf wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(arrDefault(1, i)) Then
        updateBookmark CStr(arrDefault(1, i)), arrDefault(2, i), arrDefault(3, i)
        End If
```

Update Bookmark Subroutine:

```
Private Sub updateBookmark(bookmarkname As String, bookmarkValue As Variant, ValueType As String)
Dim BMRange As Word.Range
    DeleteFormFields (bookmarkname)
    Set BMRange = wdapp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkname).Range
'if the language is French
If InStr(1, UCase(strLang), "FRENCH") <> 0 Then
    Select Case ValueType
    Case "Date"
         If bookmarkname = "TodaysDate" Then
            BMRange.Text = bookmarkValue
        Else
            BMRange.Text = CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(bookmarkValue, "[$-040c]d mmmm, yyyy"))
        End If
    Case "String", "Long", "Integer"
        BMRange.Text = bookmarkValue
    Case "Currency"
        BMRange.Text = Format(bookmarkValue, "$#,##0.00")
    End Select
'if the language is English
Else
    Select Case ValueType

    Case "String", "Long", "Integer"
        BMRange.Text = bookmarkValue
    Case "Currency"
        BMRange.Text = Format(bookmarkValue, "$#,##0.00")
    Case "Date"
        If bookmarkname = "TodaysDate" Then BMRange.Text = Format(bookmarkValue, "MMMM D, YYYY")
        BMRange.Text = Format(bookmarkValue, "MMMM D YYYY")
    End Select
End If
    wdapp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkname, BMRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your `ValueType` parameter smells like it could use some `VbVarType` enum instead of these stringly-typed hard-coded values.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: "not working" and "malfunctioning" don't tell us much about what actually happens when you run the code.  Do you see errors, if so which errors exactly?  Does nothing happen?

Comment: That's a good idea with ValueType, I'll convert it to an enum instead moving forward :).

Comment: I'll be a little more specific. Essentially the real issue is that the code below is on my computer saying that the bookmark exists and on other computers is intermittently saying that the bookmark exists. Meaning that if a document has 15 bookmarks it will skip 2 bookmarks as if they didn't exist.

Comment: ElseIf wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(arrDefault(1, i)) Then
        updateBookmark CStr(arrDefault(1, i)), arrDefault(2, i), arrDefault(3, i)
        End If

Comment: array starts at 0 vs array starts at 1? That's a setting in vba options that could vary between machines.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll look into on the machines today, I'm going to debug the code in more detail to see if the dll files differ from my machine to theirs, I'm going to make sure that the array is being picked up properly (the array has 3 columns first is the bookmark name, second is the user value and the 3rd is the data type). I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I did a little research It's most likely because of a missing reference. This person was apparently getting a similar issue. I'll let you know if the references are the issue, if so it shouldn't be too hard to update their references or update my code to late binding as that may resolve my issue. Here is where I found some more information: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b90ed5cc-6bd1-46b4-bbea-de4a15521b26/detect-and-remove-missing-references-in-vba-code?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! There was a missing ValueType called "Month" This was making the bookmark not update.... as for the references they were fine... Thanks to those who took the time to look into this.